# multiple python interpreter with different locations

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, interpreter

anybody know why I have something like this?
why they are with the same name but they have different locations?
which one should i use ?

[image]

ps:
I should say that I did add these two lines to .bashrc 
export PATH="${PATH}:/home/qr8v/.local/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/qr8v/.local/bin"
because I had a problem. it was saying that scripts were installed in a folder that is not on PATH. then I added these two lines to .bashrc

Comment: check your system variables. Maybe they are duplicated there.

Comment: What is the output of running this command `echo $PATH` in terminal??

Comment: @Anwarvic this is the outcome of that /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/qr8v/.local/bin:/home/qr8v/.local/bin

Comment: @Wippo with printenv? I did that but I didn't get anything from it.

Comment: @daan could you open `/bin` on your machine and search for `python`. If found, then Python is installed in two places. If not found, maybe something wrong in `.bashrc`. Anyway, it's not a big deal. You can choose any one of them with no problem

Answer (score 1):

I always stick to the `/usr/bin/path`, here is the link with some explanation between those two: [bin vs usr/bin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/difference-between-bin-and-usr-bin).

If you make some virtual envs, they will be listed here as well, and it is always good to use virtual environments for bigger projects. You can look that up [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: can it be the result of adding /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/qr8v/.local/bin:/home/qr8v/.local/bin to bashrc? because before that whenever I did want to use the package it did say that it doesn't exist but after adding those the problem solved.

Comment: If you want to see where the path of some program is, you can use 'whereis program_name', and you'll see that there are often multiple paths. For example, if I run 'whereis python3' I get more than 10 paths because of virtual envs. The important thing is to know which path is for which project, and that's all.